# Resolve Ljava.lang.Object

Tags: json, list, jpa, jpql

What doest Ljava.lang.Object mean? I have List that I made using JPQL like this:

public List findLast5Articles() {

```
    return entityManager
            .createQuery("SELECT a.title, a.created, SUBSTRING(a.content, 1, 200) " +
                    "FROM " +Article.class.getName() +" a ORDER BY a.created DESC")
            .setMaxResults(5)
            .getResultList();
}
```

When I try to show this on my json it shows only Ljava.lang.Object five times. What can I do to make it right?

Comment: what is the purpose of the construct "Article.class.getName()" in your example? why not simply use "Article"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to obtain typed resultsets in JPA, you need to specify the entity type. In your example, you can use:

```
return entityManager.createQuery("SELECT a.title, a.created, SUBSTRING(a.content, 1, 200) FROM Article a ORDER BY a.created DESC", Article.class).setMaxResults(5).getResultList();
```

See java persistence docs here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html

Specifically, the difference between [createQuery(String qlString)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createQuery-java.lang.String-) and [createQuery(String qlString, Class resultClass)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createQuery-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-)